# How can I unit test onClick if it not have an mouse click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jestjs, enzyme

I have onClick function

```
    private onClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
        if (e) {
            this.props.log();
        }
    }
```

How I can test using jest, enzyme if onClick has an event

```
it("should not log if has mouse event", () => {
    const onClickSpy = jest.fn();
    const logSpy = jest.fn();

    const props = {
        onClick: onClickSpy,
        log: logSpy,
    };
    const subject = mountProvider(ButtonWithLog, props);
    subject.find(ButtonWithLog).simulate("click"); // I needed without mouse event
    expect(logSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
it("should not log if has mouse event", () => {
    const props = {
        onClick: onClickSpy,
        log: logSpy,
    };
    const subject = mountProvider(ButtonWithLog, props);
    const onClickSpy = jest.spyOn(subject.instance(), "onClick");
    const event = { target: {} };
    subject.find(ButtonWithLog).simulate("click", event);
    expect(onClickSpy.mock.calls).to.have.length(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters into the simulate function which will be forwarded to the executing function.

```
const mockEvent = { target: {} };
subhect.find(...).simulate('click', mockEvent);
```

See more info here: [Passing an event object to enzyme .simulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921183/passing-an-event-object-to-enzyme-simulate).