# jest enzyme simulate('click') with event object and value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a problem when I try to pass via simulate, event object with values.
I am getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

  at SingleSymbol.handleLotChange.event [as handleLotChange] (src/containers/SingleSymbol.js:95:46)
  at onClick (src/containers/SingleSymbol.js:145:40)
  at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:332:27
```

I have seen [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921183/passing-an-event-object-to-enzyme-simulate) however I need to pass entire event object created as follows:

```
const event = new Event('click', {"target":{"value":8}})
```

because in the function handling the 'click' event I am using stopPropagation function

```
handleLotChange = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    this.setState({lotValue: event.target.value})
  }
```

fragment of tested component:

```
(...)
          <Grid item xs={4}  >
            <TextField
              label="Lot"
              id="lot-value"
              value={this.state.lotValue}
              onChange={(event) => this.handleLotChange(event)}
              onClick={(event) => this.handleLotChange(event)}
              type="number"
              className={classes.lotGrid}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
              inputProps={{ min: "0", max: "10", step: "0.01" }}
            />
          </Grid>
(...)
```

test itself:

```
  it('captures inserted Lot value', () => {
    const event = new Event('click', {"target":{"value":8}})
    const wrapper = shallow(<SingleSymbol data={dummy} classes={styles(theme)} />)
    wrapper.find('WithStyles(Paper)').simulate('click')
    wrapper.find('#lot-value').simulate('click', event)
    console.log(wrapper.state())
  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an actual event to pass to `simulate`, you can just pass an plain object with the data your handler function needs. So you can just do:

```
wrapper.find('#lot-value').simulate('click', {"target":{"value":8}})
```

Edit: if you need any default event behaviours, you can add dummy functions in place of them (or even mocks if you want to test that they are actually called). e.g.

```
wrapper.find('#lot-value').simulate('click', {
  target: { value: 8 },
  stopPropagation: () => {},
})
```

Comment: Doing so I get error: TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function

      at SingleSymbol.handleLotChange.event [as handleLotChange] (src/containers/SingleSymbol.js:94:13)
      at onClick (src/containers/SingleSymbol.js:145:40)

Comment: You'll need to manually add a stopPropagation function to your object. Have edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: Is there a way to set `currentTarget` in the mock event object? I’m setting it the same way as the `target` property above, but it isn’t getting picked up by the event handler.