# In React JS, how to do unit testing on a function which is in a container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to simulate on click of a button and test what's happening based on that click. I tried mocking function. But didn't work. How do we test the statements inside of a function?

I tried mocking a function to see if it has been called. But i always get mock function not called

```
updateSelect =(e, model) => {
    window.alert('test');
    const value = e.type === "keyup" ? 
    e.target.parentNode.childNodes[2].innerText : e.target.innerText;
    if(!isEmpty(value)){
      this.setState({text: value});
      this.props.returnedValue({name : model, value});
    }
}

<button className="test" onClick={(e)=>this.updateSelect(e, model)}>Click</button>
```

I expect either the function should be called or at least few statements in the function has to be executed

Comment: if you want to do unit testing you should use some unit testing library, you can look into enzyme or react-testing-library

Comment: It looks like you are trying to test implementation details. Maybe you should consider changing the approach instead of solving this particular problem. Here is an article to start with https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock function which is inside the component. You have to get element by className or element and simulate click event. While simulating click event make sure that you are passing that 2 params(Mock 2 params and pass it). Hope you are using Enzyme and Jest/Mocha. For your reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43921235/2878777).

Also in assertions check the expected output of the function(Value in state, etc) and don't check whether the function is called or not.